# How to add scalatest tags to a report?

Tags: scala, junit, scalatest

My scalatest tests use tagging functionality and look like the following:

```scala
"A test" should "test something" taggedAs (Smoke) in {
 ....
}
```

Is there a chance to **add tags to junit report** which is generated using -u option from scalatest runner?

Was trying to look everywhere but couldn't find any answer except how to disable/enable tests based on these Tags objects.

Answer (score 6):

[scalatest-custom-reporter-example](https://github.com/mario-galic/scalatest-custom-reporter-example) is a working example showing how to create custom [`Reporter`](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1-2.12/org/scalatest/Reporter.html)
and pass tags as [custom information](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1-2.12/org/scalatest/Informer.html) 
to the reporter.

[`JUnitXmlReporter`](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/blob/5fc7c4b05e1777ae64d915e0b029e9f1bfc79c3d/scalatest/src/main/scala/org/scalatest/tools/JUnitXmlReporter.scala) 
generates report in JUnit's XML format when configured via [`-u` argument](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_runner):

```
Test / testOptions += Tests.Argument("-u", "target")
```

Given the following test:

```scala
class HelloSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers  {

 object Slow extends Tag("Slow")
 object Unreliable extends Tag("Unreliable")

 "The Hello object" should "say hello" taggedAs (Slow) in {
   assert(true)
 }

 it should "sing lullaby" taggedAs (Unreliable, Slow) in {
   assert(true)
 }
}
```

by default,
[JUnitXmlReporter.xmlify](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/blob/5fc7c4b05e1777ae64d915e0b029e9f1bfc79c3d/scalatest/src/main/scala/org/scalatest/tools/JUnitXmlReporter.scala#L343)
outputs the following string:

```
...
  <testcase 
    name="The Hello object should say hello" classname="example.HelloSpec" time="0.011">
  </testcase>
  <testcase 
    name="The Hello object should sing lullaby" classname="example.HelloSpec" time="0.001">
  </testcase>
...
```

while we would like to add test's [tags](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/tagging_your_tests) to the report like so:

```
...
  <testcase 
    name="The Hello object should say hello" tag="Set(Slow)" classname="example.HelloSpec" time="0.011">
  </testcase>
  <testcase 
    name="The Hello object should sing lullaby" tag="Set(Unreliable, Slow)" classname="example.HelloSpec" time="0.001">
</testcase>
...
```

#### How to create custom reporter?

1. Create custom reporter by extending [`JUnitXmlReporter`](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/blob/5fc7c4b05e1777ae64d915e0b029e9f1bfc79c3d/scalatest/src/main/scala/org/scalatest/tools/JUnitXmlReporter.scala):

   ```
   package org.scalatest.tools
   class JUnitReporterWithTags extends JUnitXmlReporter("target")
   ```
2. Add member map to hold suite's [`tags`](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/blob/5fc7c4b05e1777ae64d915e0b029e9f1bfc79c3d/scalatest/src/main/scala/org/scalatest/Suite.scala#L912) by test name:

   ```
   private var tags: Map[String, Set[String]] = Map.empty
   ```
3. Override [`xmlify`](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/blob/5fc7c4b05e1777ae64d915e0b029e9f1bfc79c3d/scalatest/src/main/scala/org/scalatest/tools/JUnitXmlReporter.scala#L343) to inject the tags in the output string:

   ```
     override def xmlify(testsuite: Testsuite): String = {
       var xml = super.xmlify(testsuite)
       for (testcase <- testsuite.testcases) yield {
         xml = xml.replace(s""""${testcase.name}"""", s""""${testcase.name}" tag="${tags(testcase.name)}"""" )
       }
       xml
     }
   ```

#### How to pass suite's tags as custom information to the reporter?

1. Mixin [`BeforeAndAfterAll`](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1-2.12/org/scalatest/BeforeAndAfterAll.html) trait in the test:

   ```
   class HelloSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers with BeforeAndAfterAll {
   ```
2. Piggyback [`Suite.tags`](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1-2.12/org/scalatest/Suite.html#tags:Map[String,Set[String]]) 
   as `payload` argument of [`InfoProvided`](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1-2.12/org/scalatest/events/InfoProvided.html) event which 
   gets passed to reporter via [`Informer`](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1-2.12/org/scalatest/Informer.html):

   ```
   override def beforeAll(): Unit = {
       info("", Some(tags))
     }
   ```
3. Override `JUnitXmlReporter.apply` to extract and store tags payload:

   ```
     override def apply(event: Event): Unit = {
       super.apply(event)
       event match {
         case e: InfoProvided =>
           e.payload.foreach { providedTags =>
             tags ++= providedTags.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Set[String]]]
           }

         case _ =>
       }
     }
   ```

#### How to configure SBT to produce the report via custom reporter?

1. Give fully qualified name of custom reporter `JUnitReporterWithTags` to `-C argument`:

   ```
   Test / testOptions += Tests.Argument("-C", "org.scalatest.tools.JUnitReporterWithTags")
   ```
2. Produce the report with `sbt test`
3. Report should be created at `target/TEST-example.HelloSpec.xml`

Comment: This a wonderful answer Mario! Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I wanted to see :)
Couple of things which could be changed:

* when there is no taggedAs() at all it fails on java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found
* if I specify different directory than "target"(e.g. target/junit-custom-reports) it fails as well

These things I've noticed during some initial testing, anyway once again thanks a lot!